# failure when trying to invoke an ANT target for several times

Tags: java, javascript, ant, handlebars.js

I am using ANT to precompile handblebars in build time. I follow the way here http://blog.selvakn.in/2012/05/precompiling-handlerbars-tempates-with.html. And for only one target, it works very well. But then I try to invoke the target twice like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><project basedir="."  default="echoIt" name="precompile">
<property name="charset" value="utf-8"/>

<target name="echoIt">
</target>   



<target name="precompile-templates0" depends="echoIt">
      <property name="outputJS" value="../../jsp/jsp_1/js/templates0.js"/>
      <property name="templatesPath" value="../../jsp/jsp_1/js/tmpl"/>

      <java dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true" fork="true" jar="../../lib/js.jar">
        <arg value="../../otherFiles/lib/rhino-handlebars-compiler.js"/>
        <arg value="--handlebars"/>
        <arg value="../../otherFiles/third-party/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"/>
        <arg value="--templates"/>
        <arg value="${templatesPath}"/>
        <arg value="--output"/>
        <arg value="${outputJS}"/>
      </java>
      <echo>Template Precompiled to web/js/compiled-templates.js</echo>
        <echo> is now ready to compress....</echo>
</target>

<target name="precompile-templates1" depends="echoIt">
      <property name="outputJS" value="../../jsp/jsp_2/js/templates1.js"/>
      <property name="templatesPath" value="../../jsp/jsp_2/js/tmpl"/>
        <echo> is now precompiling the second one </echo>
      <java dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true" fork="true" jar="../../lib/js.jar">
        <arg value="../../otherFiles/lib/rhino-handlebars-compiler.js"/>
        <arg value="--handlebars"/>
        <arg value="../../otherFiles/third-party/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"/>
        <arg value="--templates"/>
        <arg value="${templatesPath}"/>
        <arg value="--output"/>
        <arg value="${outputJS}"/>
      </java>
      <echo>Template Precompiled to web/js/compiled-templates.js</echo>
        <echo> is now ready to compress....</echo>
 </target></project>
```

The output on the console is like this:

```
 Buildfile:   F:\AffirmedNetworks\ServerAutomation\cache\subBuildTarget\precompileTarget.xml
 echoIt:
 precompile-templates0:
 [echo] Template Precompiled to web/js/compiled-templates.js
 [echo]  is now ready to compress....
  echoIt:
  precompile-templates1:
  [echo]  is now precompiling the second one 
  [echo] Template Precompiled to web/js/compiled-templates.js
  [echo]  is now ready to compress....
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  Total time: 2 seconds
```

As you can see, the build is successful. However when I check the outputs in the expected directory, only a ‘templates0.js’ is generated in the path:jsp/jsp_1/js/. There is nothing in the path: jsp/jsp_2/js/. However, it should have on named 'templates1.js' in this folder. This is really weird. No errors occurred and the first on is generated successfully, but the second one disappeared. Can someone give me some help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in your re-use of the `<property>` task!

`Properties` are **immutable:** *whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.* i.e. once you assign a value to an *identifier* using `<property>`, it cannot be changed. See [**HERE**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)

although, you set the values to `outputJS` and `templatesPath` within both targets separately, maybe assuming/expecting *local scope*, that is not the case in `ant`.

- **reason:** *In general properties are of global scope, i.e. once they have been defined they are available for any task or target invoked subsequently*
- **exception:**  *it is not possible to set a property in a child build process created via the ant, antcall or subant tasks and make it available to the calling build process*

therefore, the values for `outputJS` and `templatesPath`, as defined in the target `precompile-templates0`, are **retained throughout the build**.

to solve your issue, you may do either of the following:

- change property names, for eg to ***outputJS1*** and ***templatesPath1*** in the target `precompile-templates1`
- (*if you're using `Ant 1.8.0` or above*) use the `<local>` task instead of the `<property>` task for declaring `outputJS` and `templatesPath`. See [**HERE**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) for this.
- use the `<var>` task of `ant-contrib`. See [**ant-contrib**](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) and [**var task**](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html).

Comment: WOW,this sounds the solution. I will have a try for the solution1! If it works, I will accept your answer, thanks!